# Why are the Borel subsets on $\mathbb R$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, sigma-algebra

I am a newbie in mathematical statistics and haven't learnt any group theory before. My lecture notes are too brief. How can the Borel subsets on $\mathbb R$ satisfy A.2 and A.3 of a $\sigma$-algebra ?

A.2 is closure under complement. A.3 is under countable unions.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Rob: I think this question will be closed virtually instantaneously on MathOverflow as off-topic (not research-math level). One might debate whether it is better placed here or on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com), though. Right now the question is unanswerable (what is A.2 and A.3?), but it will be a duplicate over there once this is clarified.

Comment: @vitasoy: You'll need to provide a little more context. We could *guess* what A.2 and A.3 are, but it would be much better for you to edit the question to include the precise statements you are wondering about. Cheers.

Comment: Dear @vitasoy: We know what a $\sigma$-algebra is. What we don't know is what your notes say under "A.2" and "A.3". I can guess that it's probably closure under complements (A.2) and under countable unions (A.3), but you need to make the question self-contained for us to know for sure. Cheers. :-)

Comment: I vote to re-open after the edit, but with a caution: because answers can easily be found in many places, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Generating_the_Borel_algebra), the continuation of this thread is predicated on its comments and answers maintaining a focus on the topics and applications emphasized in our [faq] and meeting the usual criteria for quality applied to all SE sites.  BTW, vitasoy, it will be fruitless to look in the group theory literature for information about sigma algebras!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to prove the axioms A2,A3.
You define the set of Borel sets as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the open intervals (or equivalently closed, half-open, compact intervals etc.) Call the set of all open intervals U. 
The smallest $\sigma$-algebra can be defined as the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain U. This intersection is non-empty since the set of all sets has that property. The fact that an arbitrary intersection of  $\sigma$-algebras is itself a $\sigma$- algebra is straightforward.